# Foreign Key Constraint - Django API

Tags: mysql, django

I am trying to set a the id of the user table as foriegn key in the members table but i get the error thrown below. What could i not be doing right here? I seem not to understand the error
**error**

```
Internal Server Error: /team/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 489, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 486, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 244, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 21, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 26, in perform_create
    serializer.save()
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 215, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 916, in create
    instance = ModelClass.objects.create(**validated_data)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 394, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 806, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 836, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 922, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 961, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1061, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1099, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 101, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`peaceapp`.`peace_teammember`, CONSTRAINT `peace_teammember_owner_id_2c587836_fk_auth_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`))')
```

**model**

```
class PeaceHero(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    last_name= models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name = 'peacehero', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')

class TeamMember(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    last_name= models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name = 'captain', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
```

**serliazer**

```
class PeaceHeroSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.id')
    class Meta:
        model = PeaceHero
        fields = ('url','id', 'first_name','last_name','quote','owner')


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
     peacehero =  serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='peacehero-detail', read_only=True)
     captain = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='team-details',read_only=True)
     class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = ('url','id','username', 'password','peacehero','captain')

class TeamMemberSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.id')
    class Meta:
        model = TeamMember
        fields = ('id','first_name','last_name','owner')
```

**view**

```
class PeaceHeroList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = PeaceHero.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PeaceHeroSerializer
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

#retrieve or delete or update pece heroes.
class PeaceHeroDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = PeaceHero.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PeaceHeroSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                      IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

#list all registered users
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

#retrieve a user from database
class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

#retrieve a team member 
class TeamList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = TeamMember.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TeamMemberSerializer
```

Comment: add the full stacktrace and your view

Comment: @e4c5 stacktrace adn view updated

Comment: Stacktrace unfortunately doesn't have the view that caused the eerror. What endpoint were you hitting when this happened?

Comment: TeamMemers Endpoint. I am trying to add a team member who would belong to the logged in user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right path but here is the case that the database is expecting an `owner id` with its respective user. I am quite sure you migrated the peace_teammember later in the project. Delete the tables if possible the database and retry.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's a row in `peace_teammember` that has a `owner_id` value that doesn't have a corresponding record in `auth_user`.

Find the team members that have a owner_id that doesn't exist in the users table. Delete them or create the corresponding users, then create the foreign key.

Comment: as at now, my peace_temmember is empty. What i currently trying to do is, when i enter info for the team member, the id of the currently logged user should be filled in the owner_id of the peace_teammember. That is what i did for the PeaceHeroSerializer if you can see :)